# Moving Git repository content to another repository preserving history

Tags: git, merge, repository, migrate

I am trying to move only the contents of one repository (`repo1`) to another existing repository (`repo2`) using the following commands:

```
git clone repo1
git clone repo2
cd repo1
git remote rm origin
git remote add repo1
git push
```

But it's not working. I reviewed a similar post, but I only found one moving the folder, not the contents.

Comment: Do you want to have the contents of repo1 as a branch on repo2, or as part of master, so the folders of both repos coexist in your working dir?

Comment: I want to move it as a part of master.

Comment: This tutorial is perfect! http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/05/19/moving-git-repository-new-server/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to move files from one git repo to another (not a clone), preserving history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1365541/how-to-move-files-from-one-git-repo-to-another-not-a-clone-preserving-history)

Comment: not a duplicate, that's a different question

Comment: For GitHub users, you can import another repo via https://github.com/new/import

Comment: there is simple answer here that worked first time for me: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47559855/git-move-repository-to-a-subfolder-of-another-repository

Answer (score 455, accepted):

I think the commands you are looking for are:

```
cd repo2
git checkout master
git remote add r1remote **url-of-repo1**
git fetch r1remote
git merge r1remote/master --allow-unrelated-histories
git remote rm r1remote
```

After that `repo2/master` will contain everything from `repo2/master` and `repo1/master`, and will also have the history of both of them.

Comment: Chronial, the above comands didnt work! it didnt copied the history.

Comment: OK, now it worked. I used the following command;cd repo2, 
> git remote rm origin
> git remote add origin **url-of-repo1**, 
> git fetch r1remote > git push origin master

Comment: Notice that the behavior seem to have changed - now an error is thrown unless an option is provided to the merge command, stating that it is ok to merge 2 unrelated histories. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/37938036/6095334

Comment: I need to destroy de original repo1, and I am supposing that with this recipe here have no problem with the life of `url-of-repo1` ... But, if I used another recipe? Cloning with modern git  with `--mirror` (as in the recipe of the link) **will be the same?**   https://help.github.com/articles/duplicating-a-repository/#mirroring-a-repository

Comment: Excellent answer. RE the comments on branches, for each branch you want to migrate, I think you have to 1) create and checkout the branch in your new repo and then 2) run the answer's `git merge` command, substituting the name of the branch you're migrating. Maybe this could be scripted, but I only had a few branches to migrate, so I didn't bother scripting it.

Comment: Is it possible to add repo2 as a folder in repo1? If you are merging multiple repositories it would make it easier.

Comment: @Yodiz the easiest way to achieve that is to just move everything in repo2 into a subfolder and commit that. Then follow the steps in the answer.

Comment: @Chronial
Is there a way to extract/merge code of `repo1` into a specific directory of `repo2`? Currently, it's extracting all the contents in the root of `repo2`?

Comment: @abhijithda The simplest solution would be to just move everything inside `repo1` into a subfolder (inside `repo1`) before you do the merge.

Comment: Please note that `--allow-unrelated-histories` was introduced in `git-2.9.0` and older versions of `git` don't need that option (like centos 7 :D).

Comment: You might come across "Your branch is based on 'origin/master', but the upstream is gone.
  (use "git branch --unset-upstream" to fixup)"
As a solution : git push --set-upstream origin master

Answer (score 151):

Perfectly described here https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/05/moving-git-repository-new-server/

First, we have to fetch all of the remote branches and tags from the existing repository to our local index:

```
git fetch origin
```

We can check for any missing branches that we need to create a local copy of:

```
git branch -a
```

Let’s use the SSH-cloned URL of our new repository to create a new remote in our existing local repository:

```
git remote add new-origin git@github.com:manakor/manascope.git
```

Now we are ready to push all local branches and tags to the new remote named new-origin:

```
git push --all new-origin 
git push --tags new-origin
```

Let’s make new-origin the default remote:

```
git remote rm origin
```

Rename new-origin to just origin, so that it becomes the default remote:

```
git remote rename new-origin origin
```

Comment: Can confirm that this copies the entire history and tags. Very nice. Thanks.

Comment: If the new-origin has no any commit, it works well. However, if there is any commit in the new-origin, the way mentioned here won't word as expected.

Comment: you need to swtich branchs with `git checkout BranchName` then push branch to remote repo again with `git push --all new-origin ` but thanks a lot

Comment: To fetch all branches to local and then add the remote: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21189710/9247792

Comment: this seems not to be working if you use LFS already..

Answer (score 58):

If you're looking to preserve the existing branches and commit history, here's one way that worked for me.

```
git clone --mirror https://github.com/account/repo.git cloned-repo
cd cloned-repo
git push --mirror {URL of new (empty) repo}

# at this point only remote cloned-repo is correct, local has auto-generated repo structure with folders such as "branches" or "refs"
cd ..
rm -rf cloned-repo
git clone {URL of new (empty) repo}
# only now will you see the expected user-generated contents in local cloned-repo folder

# note: all non-master branches are avaialable, but git branch will not show them until you git checkout each of them
# to automatically checkout all remote branches use this loop:
for b in `git branch -r | grep -v -- '->'`; do git branch --track ${b##origin/} $b; done
```

Now, suppose you want to keep the source and destination repos in sync for a period of time. For example, there's still activity within the current remote repo that you want to bring over to the new/replacement repo.

```
git clone -o old https://github.com/account/repo.git my-repo
cd my-repo
git remote add new {URL of new repo}
```

To pull down the latest updates (assuming you have no local changes):

```
git checkout {branch(es) of interest}
git pull old
git push --all new
```

NB: I have yet to use submodules, so I don't know what additional steps might be required if you have them.

Comment: This worked simply and easily for me. I think it should be the checked answer. If you have 60 branches, this is the way to go.

Comment: Useful for mentioning the remote branches and the command to obtain them

Comment: Is it possible to mirror clone from one remote to another remote? without using local machine disk?

Answer (score 28):

This worked to move my local repo (including history) to my remote github.com repo.  After creating the new empty repo at GitHub.com I use the URL in step three below and it works great.

```
git clone --mirror <url_of_old_repo>
cd <name_of_old_repo>
git remote add new-origin <url_of_new_repo>
git push new-origin --mirror
```

I found this at: https://gist.github.com/niksumeiko/8972566

Comment: This is the easiest way to let the original repository. It also copies all branches.

Comment: This also copies all of the tags.

Comment: This is the best way to deep clone from one git to other git

Comment: great answer, it works as expected.

Comment: this copies any active branch, commits history from the old to new repo and it will delete any branch in new repo if it didnt exist in the old repo, very nice thanks

Answer (score 24):

### Mirroring a repository

As per @Dan-Cohn answer Mirror-push is your friend here. This is my go to for migrating repos:

1．Open Git Bash.

2．Create a bare clone of the repository.

```
$ git clone --bare https://github.com/exampleuser/old-repository.git
```

3．Mirror-push to the new repository.

```
$ cd old-repository.git
$ git push --mirror https://github.com/exampleuser/new-repository.git
```

4．Remove the temporary local repository you created in step 1.

```
$ cd ..
$ rm -rf old-repository.git
```

Reference and Credit: https://help.github.com/en/articles/duplicating-a-repository

Comment: the question was how to "move", not "migrate".  your answer seems to mirror the repo so that the original repo continues to exist? (I'm not sure what "mirror" does)

Comment: as a question: if I wanted to put the old repo into a specific folder of the new repo, how would  that be done?

Comment: The question was how to duplicate a repo and preserve history. Your looking for --allow-unrelated-histories https://johno.com/move-directory-between-repos-with-git-history 
If this doesn't help please ask a separate question.

Comment: All went fine. Except a small issue. The default branch changed from master to the one that had latest changes. My repo was within an org and I had to mail for requesting to change it back.

Answer (score 23):

Simplest approach if the code is already tracked by Git then set new repository as your "origin" to push to.

```
cd existing-project
git remote set-url origin https://clone-url.git
git push -u origin --all
git push origin --tags
```

Comment: I made the mistake of removing original-repo remote and adding the new-repo remote, without copying the commit history. So all the changes I made on the original repo were missing in the new repo. This worked like a charm, new repo has all my changes. Cheers mate!

Answer (score 6):

If you are migrating from a **github repo to another github repo**

I would recommend migrating with: `git clone --bare <URL>` as opposed to: `git clone --mirror` because if you mirror a github repo, it will **not only** clone the source code related things **but also** clone remaining pull requests and github references, causing an `! [remote rejected]` error when pushing.

[I am talking about this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34265266/remote-rejected-errors-after-mirroring-a-git-repository)

The procedure I recommend:

1. `git clone --bare <Old Repo Url>`
2. `cd <path to cloned repo>`
3. `git push --mirror <New Repo Url>`

Successfully migrated all branches, history and source code to github new repo without any errors!

Answer (score 6):

For those using GitHub, you can import another repository (including history) via the web UI:

https://github.com/new/import

[image]

Comment: this approach only  seems to work when the new repository doesn't already exist.  in my case I want to combine several repos into one.  so I can't seem to use this :(

Answer (score 3):

What I did:

1. Clone repository to a folder
2. `cd existing-project`
3. open here a git terminal
4. `git remote set-url origin <NEW_GIT_REPO>`
5. `git push -u origin --all`
6. `git push origin --tags`

Answer (score 2):

I used the below method to migrate my GIT Stash to GitLab by maintaining all branches and commit history.

Clone the old repository to local.

```
git clone --bare <STASH-URL>
```

Create an empty repository in GitLab.

```
git push --mirror <GitLab-URL>
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're close. Assuming that it's not just a typo in your submission, step 3 should be `cd repo2` instead of repo1. And step 6 should be `git pull` not push. Reworked list:

1. `git clone repo1`
2. `git clone repo2`
3. `cd repo2`
4. `git remote rm origin`
5. `git remote add repo1`
6. `git pull`
7. `git remote rm repo1`
8. `git remote add newremote`

Comment: Thanks Eric, but in step 3 i want to remove the link of the original repository to avoid making any remote changes.. as i want to move contents from repo1 to repo2.

Comment: Alright. I've edited my answer to try to reflect that. Just to make sure, you're trying to make a repository, repo2, that is a copy of repo1 but does not keep either repo1 or origin as remotes?

Comment: No, I am not trying to make a new repo "repo2". Actually, i have an existing repo2 which have other contents init. Now i want to move all of repo1 contents into repo2 with the history. I will keep the repo1 empty as it is in the server.

Comment: Have you considered not using git? It seems like you could probably just copy the files (via a gui or scp or ftp) and manually add them to your git repo. It might not be as efficient, but it's likely simpler.

Comment: I already tried it but it left the history. I want to move all of its history as well.

Answer (score 1):

Some of these methods dint work out for me as the new repo where I wanted to shift contents had one initial commit already made with some changes when setting up new repo (files like README etc.)

Steps that worked for me:

1.In github remote of repo1 create a new branch from master(say `snapshot`).

2.Mirror repo1 in local

```
 git clone --mirror **url-of-repo1**
```

3.Navigate to repo1 and then set new remote to the repo2:

```
git remote remove origin
git remote add origin **url-of-repo2**
```

4.Push all tracks and tags to new remote. master will get rejected but rest all are will be fine:

```
git push --all
git push --tags
```

5.Clear out mirrored repo from local:

```
rm -rf repo1.git
```

6.Clone the repo2 now in local, then navigate inside:

```
git clone **url-of-repo2.git**
cd repo2
```

7.Checkout to `snapshot` branch then:

```
git checkout --track origin/snapshot
```

8.Checkout to master and then merge with snapshot:

```
git merge snapshot  --allow-unrelated-histories
```

9.Fix conflicts and add commit for modifications to complete merge:

```
git add README.md 
git commit -m "merge track to master"
```

10.Check logs to see all commits present properly. Then push to remote:

```
git push origin master
```

Answer (score 0):

There is one way to copy a git repo, including all history and tags and branches, **that is extremely simple**! I've seen a lot of complicated answers, but found one answer that's very easy. It's taken from https://dev.to/ismailpe/duplicating-a-github-repo-with-history-3223 , here it is:

1. Create a new repository (either using git command line, or on github.com)
2. Using a command line, clone the existing/old repository: `git clone --bare https://oldRepoURL`
3. Navigate to the folder that got created `cd oldRepoURL`
4. Push the new folder to the new repository `git push --mirror https://newRepoURL`

That's it. Extremely simple!

Answer (score -2):

I am not very sure if what i did was right, but it worked anyways. I renamed repo2 folder present inside repo1, and committed the changes. In my case it was just one repo which i wanted to merge , so this approach worked. Later on, some path changes were done.

Answer (score -2):

I see a lot of solutions here. The one that is a quick one liner that has worked for me in the past is to use the --mirror option. Go into the repo you want to copy first. Then assuming you have a new repo already set up, use the clone link and that's it. It will copy over all history over to your new repo.

`cd repoOne`

`git --mirror linktonewrepo.git`

Comment: It seems like your command does not exist, are you missing the actual command and `--mirror` is just a flag of some command?

Comment: unknown option: --mirror
usage: git [--version] [--help] [-C <path>] [-c <name>=<value>]
           [--exec-path[=<path>]] [--html-path] [--man-path] [--info-path]
           [-p | --paginate | -P | --no-pager] [--no-replace-objects] [--bare]
           [--git-dir=<path>] [--work-tree=<path>] [--namespace=<name>]
           <command> [<args>]