# Move repository A's history to repository B's history (no other files)

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

I've seen a few similar problems here on StackOverflow but I haven't found 1 that fits what I need.

Here are some I've looked at that don't seem to solve my problem:

[How to move files from one git repo to another (not a clone), preserving history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1365541/how-to-move-files-from-one-git-repo-to-another-not-a-clone-preserving-history)
[Moving Git repository content to another repository preserving history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17371150/moving-git-repository-content-to-another-repository-preserving-history)

I have a repository on Bitbucket that I have added to Github. However the one on Github retains it's own history. How can I import the history from the original Bitbucket repository into the Github repository without touching the files? Both repositories already exist.

Comment: ...clone from Bitbucket, then push to GitHub?

Comment: @Ajedi32 It only seems to copy the files...all the branches and commit history from the bitbucket repo doesn't move over.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Files *can't* exist in a git repository without being on a branch. So if the files are there, there *has* to be at least one branch (`master`?) on GitHub.

Comment: @Ajedi32 Sorry, I meant `master` branch does copy over but not any of the branches or commit history (I'm not too concerned with the branches as I am history).

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "commit history". Again, there has to be at least one commit. Otherwise `master` couldn't exist (there'd be nothing for it to point to). Are you saying everything got squashed down to just one commit?

Comment: "*I've seen a few similar problems here on Stack Overflow but I haven't found 1 that fits what I need.*" **Please link to what you have looked at but didn't fit**, so that other people are better able to help you. Your question is possibly a duplicate of other questions on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Ajedi32 Okay for example: The Bitbucket repo has over 4000 commits from various team members. The Github repo that was simply a clone + added gitignore + push only shows commits for adding the files to the repo + adding gitignore.

Comment: @Cupcake Added some links that don't seem to solve my issue, thank you.

Comment: If that's the case, I'm guessing what you did was actually not a clone. Instead, you copied *all* the files manually from the old repo, added them *all* to the staging area, added the gitignore, committed, and then pushed. Is that correct?

Comment: @Ajedi32 That may be correct, it's been a while. I'm currently trying your answer below, will update if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd probably do it like this:

```
git clone --mirror <bitbucket repo>
cd <repo>
git push --mirror <github repo>
```

That basically copies *everything* from Bitbucket to GitHub, including branches, tags, and other refs.

Comment: Thank you, this works great! I have to re-add the .gitignore and READMEs but that's fine. Accepting answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the branches in your local repository, and have set it up to point to GitHub, you should be able to just do `git push origin [branch name]` for each branch. Or something like `git branch | xargs -L1 git push origin` to do them all at once.