# Need a subdirectory not a submodule

Tags: git, github

I had a git repository of 4 Assignments that I had to do for a class.  I then wanted to move all those assignments into one repository to make room for more private repositories on my git (We are only allowed so many).  When I tried to do it by just moving the files into the new directory and using git add.  This instead made submodules and that isn't what i want.  How can add these folders of code as a subdirectory and not a submodule?

Comment: Did you maybe copy the files over along with the hidden `.git` folder? This might be the issue... A folder containing a `.git` folder is considered a repository in itself...

Comment: The problem was that the .git was hidden so I couldn't find it.  Thank you!

Comment: Glad to hear you found the issue! Having a dot at the beginning of a file or folder is by convention a hidden item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want the files without the development history, you can simply copy each of the original repositories to the new one, deleting the `.git` folder in the copy-and-pasted repositories.

If you want to preserve the development history, follow the instructions in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17371150/moving-git-repository-content-to-another-repository-preserving-history).