# ! [remote rejected] errors after mirroring a git repository

Tags: git, repository, mirror

I'm following this documentation:
https://help.github.com/articles/duplicating-a-repository/

```
git clone --mirror https://github.com/exampleuser/repository-to-mirror.git

cd repository-to-mirror.git

git push --mirror https://github.com/exampleuser/mirrored
```

The output shows that the repository is pushed as a mirror, but for some reason I'm getting these errors as well:

```
 ! [remote rejected] refs/pull/1/head -> refs/pull/1/head (deny updating a hidden ref)
 ! [remote rejected] refs/pull/1/merge -> refs/pull/1/merge (deny updating a hidden ref)
```

What are these errors? Can I assume the repository was mirrored ?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

As mentioned in [this issue](https://github.com/rtyley/bfg-repo-cleaner/issues/36#issuecomment-37877829), that happens when you mirror a GitHub repo which has **pull requests** made to it.

> The refs beginning '**`refs/pull`**' are synthetic read-only refs created by GitHub - you can't update (and therefore 'clean') them, because they reflect branches that may well actually come from other repositories - ones that submitted pull-requests to you.
>
> So, while you've pushed all your real refs, the pull requests don't get updated

You would need to [mirror a GitHub repo *without* their pull requests](http://christoph.ruegg.name/blog/git-howto-mirror-a-github-repository-without-pull-refs.html).

> Simply replace the catch-all refspec above with two more specific specs to just include all heads and tags, but not the pulls, and all the remote pull refs will no longer make it into your bare mirror:

```
fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*
fetch = +refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*
fetch = +refs/change/*:refs/change/*
```

If push still fails, as [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34265266/remote-rejected-errors-after-mirroring-a-git-repository/34266401#comment124318932_34266401) by [Ofek Shilon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/89706/ofek-shilon), add the push entries:

```
push = +refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*
push = +refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*
push = +refs/change/*:refs/change/*
```

As mention in [Git Refspec](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-The-Refspec):

> The `+` tells Git to update the reference even if it isn’t a fast-forward.

---

This change is to be done on the bare repository folder `repository-to-mirror.git`, using `git config --local --edit`.

The named remote to modify is the default "`origin`" one.

The goal is to not fetch the unwanted references, and push only the ones we need.

Comment: Thanks, I went through the procedure but for some reason i'm still getting the same error. I clone the repo with --mirror, I edit the git configuration with `git config -e` and run - `git remote update` and `git push mirror` and still get the same error.

Comment: @deezx What does return `git config --get-regex remote.origin.fetch`?

Comment: This is the output- $ git config --get-regex remote.origin.fetch
remote.origin.fetch +refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*
remote.origin.fetch +refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*
  Actually, when I cloned the repository without --mirror, edited the git config as you wrote, it worked. it fetched only branches and tags, so it worked! My only question now is that I see that it didn't mirror the `refs/changes`. Is there a way to tell git to fetch ALL except for pull requests (`refs/pull`)?

Comment: @deezx no, you need to add `+refs/changes/*:refs/changes/*` for it to fetch `heads`, `tags` and `changes`, but not `pull`. Does the `git push --mirror` works after that? Make sure to try again in a new local clone (not `clone --mirror`, just simple clone, in which you add the fetch refspecs, do a `git fetch`, then `push --mirror` to another repo)

Comment: @VonC  I'm having the same trouble as deez had. On a fresh repo, added the config into your suggested fetch refspec, and push still fails with the same error.  Do you know if this recipe still works in 2021?

Comment: @OfekShilon it should still work. Try and describe your use case in a separate question, with OS and Git version.

Comment: @VonC  adding ‘push’ keys to the config, with identical refspecs, solved my problem (fetch keys weren’t enough).

Comment: @OfekShilon OK. I have edited the answer to include your comment. Thank you for this feedback.

Comment: A small aside: The '+' at the refspecs start is said to "tell Git to update the reference even if it isn’t a fast-forward" (from the Pro-git book).  Not sure if it is relevant to the `push` lines.

Comment: @OfekShilon It does. I have updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: BTW, can I just safely ignore the errors when I don't care about pull requests anyway? Do I still get all original branches, tags, notes, etc.? (Basically everything "git", that is not specific to the github platform.)

Comment: @Qwerty To be tested but yes, I assume all the rest should have been pushed.

Comment: It's not clear if this change should be done on the github remote or the remote you're pushing to.

Comment: @ChrisStryczynski Good point. I have edited the answer to make that clearer. Let me know if that edit is enough.

Comment: Hmm sorry I meant it's not clear under which `[remote ?]` (within the .git/config) this should be done under (the both have a `fetch` line, as opposed to which 'git config' this should be done to).

Comment: @ChrisStryczynski It should be the origin one. I have edited the answer.

Answer (score 41):

Full steps:

```
git clone --bare https://github.com/exampleuser/old-repository.git
cd old-repository
git push --mirror https://github.com/exampleuser/new-repository.git
```

Comment: wow, this should be the selected answer !

Comment: Easy and 100% working

Comment: Working 100%.  Some explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3959924/whats-the-difference-between-git-clone-mirror-and-git-clone-bare

Comment: +1.   This is a perfect solution if you need to mirror a repository without using the massive overhead of the --mirror option.  It handles all feature branches and tags.
 I hat to mirror a GitLab repository to another server. With the --mirror I get separate branches for each Commit that has a pipeline run associated with it.

Answer (score 17):

instead of

git clone **--mirror**

use

git clone **--bare**

[instructions](https://help.github.com/articles/duplicating-a-repository/)

Comment: That's a change in semantics. It means he won't be able to push to this remote.

Comment: Why? What's the difference?

Comment: [What's the difference between git clone --mirror and git clone --bare](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3959924/whats-the-difference-between-git-clone-mirror-and-git-clone-bare)

Answer (score 5):

Found working and simple solutions there https://www.metaltoad.com/blog/git-push-all-branches-new-remote

```
git push newremote refs/remotes/oldremote/*:refs/heads/*
```

or

```
git push newremote refs/remotes/oldremote/features/*:refs/heads/features/*
```

Answer (score 3):

(I wanted this to be a comment, but not enough reputation)

Based on @VonC's answer, this sounds like a non-problem.

> So, while you've pushed all your real refs, the pull requests don't get updated

I see two scenarios in which you want to duplicate your repository.

1. You want a backup/copy of a repo that you have full control over.
2. You're modifying the history of a repo and you need a backup locally in case you need to undo your changes.

In either case, it seems like `git clone --mirror` is your safest option because even if you see errors in your `push`, all of the non-pull request related content was successfully pushed, which takes care of scenario 1. For scenario 2, you'd want those pull request references as part of your backup.

Comment: I am more in senario 2, where I would like to fully migrate my repository (and so interested in keeping the history of any pull requests).  How would I go about a solution that keeps them intact (ie  github repo --> mirror clone --> gitlab (or other vcs))

Answer (score 1):

Adding these three lines to the git config file after the fetch = +refs/*:refs/* line fixed it for me:

```
push = +refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*
push = +refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*
push = +refs/change/*:refs/change/*
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar issuer when trying to delete some big files from gitlab by rewriting the history, following the procedure here: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/repository/reducing_the_repo_size_using_git.html

IMPORTANT: Before starting use gitlab export function to export your project, these steps went wrong for me many time before I figured it out.

The issue I faced as mentioned by others is that you can not rewrite read-only refs specifically does for PRs (merge requests as they are called in gitlab)

The obvious idea that come then is to create a new repo, but this would loose all the issues, releases...

Fortunately, gitlab allows to export you repo with all this metadata unto a zip file, that contains all the git bundled, (more info [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bundle) about git bundle).

A bundle is basically a full archive of the repo, and ou can clone form it:

```
git clone --mirror ./project.bundle
```

Not you have a mirror of your project (the same way if you have mirror cloned form the server), and you can use  [`git filter-repo`](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/main/INSTALL.md) or (BFG)[https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/] as explaind in the docs, to find the biggest files and delete them from history.

use `du -h` before and after to make sure that the size of your repo is really smaller, now you can create a new [git bundle](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bundle) with:

```
git bundle create --progress project.bundle --tags --branches master
```

although I recommend handling all branches before this procedure to avoid messing up branches.

You can replace project.build in the export downloaded from gitlab (ie create a new tar.gz with exact same structure, be careful of prefix...)
this can be done by:

```bash
tar -xvzf project_name...export.tar.gz
```

replace the project.bundle

```bash
cd project_name...export
tar -cvzf updated.tar.gz . # important to avoid messing up tar structure
```

And the re-importing the project.
You can rename you project to PROJECT_NAME-bkp in gitlab, and reimport with same name as before.

Hope it save someone else the time.