# BFG doesn't update github pull requests

Tags: github, purge, bfg-repo-cleaner

so I ran BFG, following the instructions here.  https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/  The console output from BFG looked good but, after pushing, when I got back to github, I could still find the sensitive data in pull requests > clsoed > *old merged request* > files changed.  I've seen talk about github's gc maybe taking some time.  Do I have to wait for changes to show up?

---

EDIT
I overlooked one line in the push output

 `! [remote rejected] refs/pull/1/head -> refs/pull/1/head (deny updating a hidden ref)`

Some of the text that I want to remove is in hidden files.  Is that the source?

Answer (score 1):

You need to do a `git push --force` in order to force the rewritten history of the cleaned branch to be published to the remote repo.

Only then will you see the cleaned version of those commits on GitHub.

However, as I [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34266401/6309), you cannot push back pull requests ith a global `push --mirror`. Try pushing them branch by branch with `git push --force`.