# GitLab: error: failed to push some refs to

Tags: git, gitlab

After creation of a new project in GitLab CE and pushing a repository on my PC to it with the command:

```
git push --mirror origin
```

I've got lots of errors like

```
(deny updating a hidden ref)
```

The remote is a corporate GitLab. It exists and is accessible

```
origin  ssh://git@... (fetch)
origin  ssh://git@... (push)
```

I simulated the remote by creating a directory on my file system and running in it:

```
git init --bare
```

Added this directory as a remote, named it `local` and retried the initial push with this remote:

```
git push --mirror local
```

and it worked. All the branches were copied. So what's the problem with pushing to the corporate remote? Isn't the repo in GitLab created with `git init --bare`? Are there some settings needed?

The commands that GitLab suggests at the project's page are the following:

```
    Push an existing Git repository

    cd existing_repo
    git remote rename
    origin old-origin
    git remote add origin ssh://...git
    git push -u
    origin --all git
    push -u origin --tags
```

but they only seem to push local branches. Does it mean that I have to do:

```
git checkout -b branch1 other_remote/branch1
```

for each branch from the `other_remote` so that they become local and then do the push to the corporate remote with the commands suggested at GitLab project page? This is somehow tedious...

Answer (score 0):

As [in here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54341191/6309), check your local config `git config --local -l`

If you see:

```
push = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

It should be

```
push = +refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*
```