# Jenkins Pipeline git push (after npm version) - fatal: You are not currently on a branch

Tags: git, jenkins-pipeline

I am currently trying to publish some built assets as npm package, to be able to pull it onto different environments like staging or production.

My Pipeline

- a docker agent (own image: alpine + git + ssh)
- 3 stages

  - build (npm install/build, private registry)
  - test
  - publish

    - npm version (does change package.json and package-lock.json)
    - npm publish (package is saved in private registry)
    - git add ... git commit ... (I thought those are done by npm version but...no?!)
    - **git push <= here is the problem**

The error:

```
git push HEAD:refs/remotes/origin/master
fatal: You are not currently on a branch.
To push the history leading to the current (detached HEAD)
state now, use

    git push HEAD:refs/remotes/origin/master HEAD:<name-of-remote-branch>
```

I already tried some different git push calls like:

```
git push -u ${env.GIT_BRANCH} HEAD:${env.GIT_BRANCH}
git push -u origin HEAD:${env.GIT_COMMIT}
git push HEAD:refs/remotes/${env.GIT_BRANCH}
```

With

```
GIT_BRANCH=origin/master
GIT_COMMIT=0e0037b8ec27345f83ff4e08f1cf6133d3889dda
```

git show-ref

```
0e0037b8ec27345f83ff4e08f1cf6133d3889dda refs/remotes/origin/master
```

**Update:**

After changing into a branch with `git checkout -b temp_${env.BUILD_NUMBER}` and
`git push --repo ${GIT_URL} --set-upstream ${GIT_URL} ${env.GIT_BRANCH}` the error changes to

```
 ! [remote rejected] origin/master -> origin/master (deny updating a hidden ref)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@...myrepo.git'
```

Comment: I don't know anything about Jenkins or npm, but it seems to me that Git is saying quite clearly that you're in detached head mode.

Comment: That's why I added `HEAD:refs/remotes/origin/master` but it just writes the same error and concatenates HEAD:<branch> again...but isn't that the HEAD part I already added with the master branch?

Comment: Some discussion here, don't know if it's relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34265266/remote-rejected-errors-after-mirroring-a-git-repository

Comment: The checkout happens via the jenkins git plugin (poll git every minute and build on commits). But I push via the git of the docker build agent. I guess the problems arise because of that but I found no other way to push the version change back into the repo via the jenkins plugin