# Git: move repository to a subfolder of another repository

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have two separate git repositories(in BitBucket), `Repo A` and `Repo B`. I would like to move `Repo B` into a subfolder of `Repo A`. I also need ensure that the commit history etc. in `Repo B` is preserved and not lost.

How can I achieve this with git?

Comment: plase be more specific, do you want to totally merge these two repos?

Comment: @MichałWalenciak: Yes, ideally. If there is a way without losing the commit history.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

To merge a Repo B into Repo A as a subfolder, run this command inside Repo A;

```
git subtree add -P <prefix> <repo> <rev>
```

Set `<prefix>` to the name of the subdirectory, `<repo>` to the clone URL of Repo B, and `<rev>` to the revision of Repo B you want (HEAD if latest)

This will take the history of Repo B and merge it with Repo A, along with an additional merge commit.

Comment: For anyone out googling issues of attempting to move a subfolder of **Repo A** into a subfolder a **Repo B**, I was able to resolve this issue by first following [this article from GitHub to split a subfolder into another repository](https://www.help.github.com/articles/splitting-a-subfolder-out-into-a-new-repository) (only difference is that I created a local repository for this so I stopped at step 5 and pushed this into my locally created repo). I then followed this answer to push it into a subfolder: `<prefix>` = `"My/Sub/Directory with spaces"` and it worked great!

Comment: How can I update the repo B in repo A? should I just do this again to update it?

Comment: @KennetCeleste once you merge it it's ... well ... merged. Single repo. There is no *Repo B* anymore. If you want to keep them separate look at [git submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules).

Comment: @StavAlfi are you sure about that...? I just tried this in a test git repository, and all of the history of the child repo I was cloning into a subdirectory the parent repo was duplicated in the parent repo (in a newly made branch), which is exactly what I wanted (and what I think OP wanted too)

Comment: I think I can guess the answer to this question, but just looking for confirmation, if repo B is deleted, will the contents and git history of repo B still remain in the subdirectory of repo A indefinitely?

Comment: I got a "git invalid path" error using dot on prefix like "... -P ./path/to", so I changed to "... -P path/to" and it worked. Just in case anyone have the same issue.

Answer (score 3):

It isn't done in BitBucket, it's done using git. You need the following steps:

- Fetch repo B into a cloned repo A. Git might warn you about this, but still do it.
- Checkout that fetched code (you will have only code from repo B at that moment) and move it all into a subfolder you want. Commit that.
- Checkout your repo A code again and `merge` the commit you have just created.

Comment: This will not transfer the commit history of repo A

Comment: It will keep both as a separate "parents" of the merge commit.