# How to migrate multiple repositories into a mono-repo while maintaining commit history?

Tags: git, version-control, monorepo

I'm trying to migrate a few Git repositories into one monorepo.

I have two project repositories, let's call them `project1` and `project2`. In my monorepo, I want to have a `projects` directory with two subdirectories, `project1` and `project2`. Each subdirectory should contain the files from the corresponding project, with the Git history maintained.

Is this even possible with standard Git commands?

Note: I have looked at Lerna - `lerna import` does exactly what I need, but unfortunately it only works with JS projects, and one of my projects is a Ruby project.

Comment: Similar: [Moving Git repository content to another repository preserving history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17371150/moving-git-repository-content-to-another-repository-preserving-history).

Comment: Consider using [tomono](https://github.com/unravelin/tomono), which automates the migration of many repos to one

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you merge two Git repositories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425892/how-do-you-merge-two-git-repositories)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can use git commands to achieve this.

Migrate two repos into a monorepo into subfolder `project1` and `project2`, you need to move files into project1/project2 folder of a repo, commit changes and then combine them together. Detailed steps as below:

###1. Move files into project1 and project2 folders separately
In the first repo (such as `repo1`), move files into `project1` folder as below:

```
# In local repo1 
mkdir project1
mv * project1
git add .
git commit -m 'move files into project1 folder'
git push
```

In the second repo (such as `repo2`), move files into project2 folder as below:

```
# In local repo2
mkdir project2
mv * project2
git add .
git commit -m 'move files into project2 folder'
git push
```

###2. migrate the two repos into a monorepo

In any of a local repo (such as in local `repo1`), execute the below commands:

```
# In local repo1
git remote add repo2 <URL for repo2> -f
git pull repo2 master --allow-unrelated-histories
```

Comment: How can I view all the previous commits for `project1`? If I do `git log -- project1` in the monorepo, there's only going to be one commit shown (i.e. `'move files into project1 folder'`). Any tips?