# How to view project logs after merging a repository into a monorepo?

Tags: git, git-log, monorepo

Suppose I have a monorepo whose directory is named `monorepo`. In the multirepo, each project has its own directory. Also suppose I have another existing repository named `project-a` that I wish to place into the monorepo.

To place `project-a` into the existing multirepo, I did this (taken from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50033287/how-to-migrate-multiple-repositories-into-a-mono-repo-while-maintaining-commit-h)):

```
# Prepare project-a.
cd ~/project-a/
mkdir project-a/
mv * project-a/
git add --all
git commit -am 'Move all files into a directory in preparation for conversion to monorepo'

# Place project-a into the monorepo.
cd ~/monorepo/
git remote add origin ~/project-a/
git fetch origin
git merge origin/master --allow-unrelated-histories
git remote rm origin
```

At this point, the history (i.e. the output of `git log`) of `project-a` has been merged seamlessly with the existing history in the monorepo. But how do I view the history of `project-a` only? i.e. How can I view the history of `project-a` as if it had not been merged into the monorepo?

I tried `git log -- project-a/`, but that only shows one commit (i.e. `'Move all files into a directory in preparation for conversion to monorepo'`), whereas I had intended to see all the commits I made for the files in `project-a`.

Comment: I assume project-a was a preexisting git repo? Then I think you should have used `git mv` instead of `mv`. Then git would know that you moved the files not that they popped up just like that on the project.

Comment: @eftshift0 Yes, `project-a` was a preexisting repository. Edited the question.

Comment: @eftshift0 I experimented with your suggestion (i.e. using `git mv` instead of `mv`). There's no difference either way. Same result.