# Can I retain commit history moving to one project to another project?

Tags: git

We are moving our code from one project to another project. But we want to retain the commit history. Please let me know if there is any way I can do this?

Comment: If you mean that you're starting a new repo with a completely new history, then the answer is, not easily.  But, if your current code can be viewed of as a dependency, then why not leave it as that, and bring it into your new project as a dependency?

Comment: Actually, It is just that we are moving our repo in diffrent GIT structure. I don't think that can be possible without creating new repo.

Comment: [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17371150/moving-git-repository-content-to-another-repository-preserving-history) for a possible solution.

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me :)

Answer (score 0):

Below is the commands to achieve this -

1. clone your new repo.
2. git checkout
3. git remote add old_remote **url-of-old-repo**
4. git fetch old_remote
5. git merge old_remote/ --allow-unrelated-histories
6. git remote rm old_remote