# Migrate changes of one gitrepo into a specific directory of another repo

Tags: git

I have to git repos: `repo1`, `repo2`. I want to move all changes from `repo1` into `repo2` preserving the history such that all files of `repo1` appear in a specific sub-directory of `repo2` root. Here is what I mean:

**Current**:

```
repo1
  |
  ...

repo2
  |
  ...
```

**Desired**:

```
repo2
  |
  --some_dir
  |     |
  |     repo1
  |       |
  ...     ...
```

Is it possible to do that preserving the history?

The solution presented in https://stackoverflow.com/a/17373088/2786156 does not really work because it moves all changes of `repo1` into `repo2` root.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+merge+two+repositories+subdirectory

Comment: In addition to the accepted answer see the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/1426163/7976758