# Is there a way to transfer all content from an old git repo to another repo?

Tags: git, github

My use case here is that i have a git repo say X and i have another git repo say Y and i need to update the repo Y with all the contents present in repo X with the commit history preserved. Can someone let me know how should i do this?

Comment: In the linked question, read the second answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/38303789/86072

Comment: @LeGEC The repo Y already has some content. Should that be fine?

Comment: What will work : all the branches and tags that are in X and not in Y will be correctly pushhed. What may need extra work : you may need to reconcile the history of the `main` branch in both repos. Ask a new question if this is your case.