# How to push existing Visual Studio project to different GitHub repository

Tags: github, visual-studio-2019

I'm working on a Windows Form application in Visual Studio 2019.
Currently, I have the project connected to a GitHub repository.

I want to simply change or switch the GitHub repository as I don't need the one I'm currently using.
I couldn't find anything clear online so I'd appreciate any help on how to do this.

Comment: Using GIT: [Moving Git repository content to another repository preserving history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17371150/moving-git-repository-content-to-another-repository-preserving-history), using [Github: Duplicating a repository](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/creating-and-managing-repositories/duplicating-a-repository)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this thread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/185141/how-do-i-access-the-remote-git-repository-for-a-vi.html), you can control what the remote refers to with `Manage Remotes`

[image: remote]

And:

[image: remote url]

You can change the repository there.