# How to "git subtree" only one file or directory?

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-subtree

I use `git subtree` like:

```
git subtree add \
   --prefix=directory_destination_path \
   --squash git@bitbucket.org:kicaj/projectname.git \
   master
```

But in `directory_destination_path`, it copies the entire repo from `projectname.git`.

How do I copy only a subdirectory or file from `projectname.git` to `directory_destination_path`?

Also, how do I update (automatic) file changes in both repositories were still the same? It is possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39479154/how-can-i-split-a-single-file-from-a-git-repo-into-a-new-repo that has an answer about extracting history of a single file using `git fast-export`.

Answer (score 31):

If I understand, you seem to want to only merge in a certain directory of a different repository, and you want it to be a subtree in your repository. I am going to call the directory of interest in the project.git `path_of_interest_in_project` and call the destination in your repo `directory_desination_path`.

Try adding the remote project.git as a remote, then checking out one of its branches locally. Then use `git-subtree split` to split out just the directory of project.git you are interested in. After that merge it into your repo using subtree merge.

```
git remote add project git@bitbucket.org:kicaj/projectname.git
git branch project_master project/master
```

The branch project_master should now store the entire history of your project.git repo.

Then you'll need to use the `git-subtrees-split` process.

```
git checkout -f project_master
git subtree split --squash --prefix=path_of_interest_in_project -b temp_branch
```

There should now be a branch called `temp_branch` containing just the directory you are interested in. Now you can perform a `git-subtree-merge` to bring it all into your repo.

```
git checkout -f master
git subtree merge --allow-unrelated-histories --prefix=directory_destination_path temp_branch
```

This should merge in the temp_branch into your master branch.

Comment: `git subtree split squash --prefix=path_of_interest_in_project temp_branch` always return: does not exist; use git subtree add

Comment: I change `path_of_interest_in_project` to `Model/Behavior` - there are directories

Comment: I would like use `repo1/Model/Behavior/file.php` to `repo2/Model/Behavior/file.php` They should always the same content regardless of which I change

Comment: I had a typo. It should be `--squash`

Comment: As far as them being in sync, theres no built in way to just automatically keep these files (only) in sync. You would have to write a script to handle it all. An easier thing might be to track these files as independent repo's and use them as subtress in both projects. This is simply not a good workflow overall.

Comment: Problems: you need to `git fetch` before you can `git branch` otherwise you get `fatal: Not a valid object name`. And when I got to the `git subtree split` I wasn't sure what to do after that because I got `fatal: ambiguous argument 'temp_branch': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.`.

Comment: There was a typo in the command. I edited it. A -b was needed before the name of the branch. It now works exactly as the OP intended.

Comment: then how to update the only one file or directory? do every steps again?

Comment: As far I can tell, `git subtree split --squash --prefix=path_of_interest_in_project -b temp_branch` only if `path_of_interest_in_project` is a directory.  In which case it grabs the commits related to all the files in that directory.  Is there a way to specify one and only one __file__?

Comment: This answer must be out of date and should be updated.  `git subtree merge` without `git subtree add` produces a "does not exist" error for me.  The `--allow-unrelated-histories` flag is not accepted either.

Comment: also `git subtree split --squash` gives "The '--squash' flag does not make sense with `git subtree split`"

Comment: Omitting `--squash` and using `git subtree add` instead of `merge --allow-unrelated-histories` worked fine in my case! :)

Answer (score 9):

Suppose you wanted to add the `images/` prefix of the octocat git repo at the ref `master`.

Suppose we want to use the remote hosted at https://github.com/octocat/octocat.github.io.git (Note: GitHub returns `error: Server does not allow request for unadvertised object` in the following `fetch` command is you specify a sha1 not associated with named ref)

Starting on the branch you wish to add the subtree to, let's first fetch the desired commit history and checkout our new branch

```
git fetch https://github.com/octocat/octocat.github.io.git master:tmp_octocat_master
git checkout tmp_octocat_master
```

Next, let's create a new history where only the files under our desired prefix (`images/`) exist.

```
git subtree split --prefix=images -b subtree_split_branch
```

Finally, let's add this subtree to our desired branch (presumably the last branch you were on, `git checkout -`)

```
git checkout -
git subtree add --prefix=public/images subtree_split_branch
```

Now you should have all the desired files on your current branch with a full git history.

## Alt Squashed history

At time you want the commits in our subtree to be squashed into a single commit.  This to a certain extent defeats the purposes of adding a subtree but it has it's place.  The following is a variation of what is described above to limit the history pulled into your repo

Starting on the branch you wish to add the subtree to:

```
git fetch --depth=1 https://github.com/octocat/octocat.github.io.git master:tmp_octocat_master
git checkout tmp_octocat_master
```

Note: we are specifying `--depth=1` in the above since we are using the `--squash` is the following `git subtree split` command.

```
git subtree split --squash --prefix=images -b subtree_split_branch
git checkout -
git subtree add --prefix=public/images subtree_split_branch
```

Comment: NOTE: I do not believe `git subtree split` currently supports specifying a single file.    It builds off and passed the `--prefix` command directly to `git read tree`. 
> --prefix=<prefix>/ 
 Keep the current index contents, and read the contents of the named tree-ish under the directory at <prefix>. The command will refuse to overwrite entries that already existed in the original index file. Note that the <prefix>/ value must end with a slash.

Comment: why do we need `public` in  `--prefix=public/images`?

Comment: Then how can this subtree get updated based on its own remote?

Answer (score 5):

It's a [great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22335955/185123) from [@eddiemoya](https://stackoverflow.com/users/845488/eddiemoya), however some commands don't work as of today. So I'll just repost them here:

```bash
# create a target branch in the new repo
git branch target

# check out the other repo into a new branch
git remote add temp git@github.com:aRepo/any-service.git
git fetch temp
git branch temp_master temp/master

# split desired folder into a temp branch
git checkout -f temp_master
git subtree split --prefix=path/to/desired/folder -b temp_branch

# check out target branch and add all commits in temp branch to the correct folder
git checkout -f target
git subtree add --prefix=path/to/destination/folder temp_branch
# ... voila

# clean up
git branch -d temp_branch
git branch -d temp_master
git remote remove temp
```

Comment: It's working for pulling the first time. What about updating the destination folder later?
I've tried `git subtree merge` but getting `refusing to merge unrelated histories`