# How to share common codes within different project with git

Tags: git, share

I have define `mongoengine schema` files in a project, now I have a new project which needs to share these files. In case I edit the schema files and I always need to synchronize files in two projects, do I have some good choice?

Here is my old project:

```
ipin.crawler.orm # this is the package I want to share
    url_index.py
    page_store.py
    user_info.py
    captcha_info.py
....
```

new project:

```
ipin.web.orm
   url_index.py
   page_store.py
   user_info.py
....
```

Comment: a submodule ? https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule

Comment: @Ôrel submodule will add the whole old project to new project, can I just add `ipin.crawler.orm` in my old project to new project?

Comment: In your old project create a submodule and add into the shared files. Then when you create a new project add the submodule to have the shared files

Comment: Use [git subtree](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22334382/git-subtree-only-one-file-or-directory)