# Move Git repo A into Git repo B (Not empty) with complete history

Tags: git, macos, version-control

I want to move all my files from Git Repo A to Git Repo B with complete history. Git B already contains another project files. I tried several ways such as

[How to move files from one git repo to another (not a clone), preserving history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1365541/how-to-move-files-from-one-git-repo-to-another-not-a-clone-preserving-history)

[How to move files from one git repo to another preserving history using `git format-patch`and `git am`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28830916/how-to-move-files-from-one-git-repo-to-another-preserving-history-using-git-for)

I tried executing all the commits via terminal. But I am getting `"git filter-branch fatal:myDirectory/: 'myDirectory' is outside repository Could not get the commits"` while executing `git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter muDirectory -- --all`.

I need detailed guidance with step by step procedure to move all files from one repo to another. Would appreciate any help, Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you expect as a result of moving a repo into another *non-empty* repo?

Comment: My Repo B already has Proj1 and Proj2. Now I want RepoA to be moved as Proj3 into RepoB with all commit history from RepoA.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Go into `repoB` and add a new remote with `repoA URL` (say, `repoA`).
- Checkout new branch (say, `branchA`) with `repoA/master history`.
- Git move all folder/file into a new sub-directory `RepoA`. Command `git mv <src> <dest>`.
- Commit your changes in `branchA`.
- Checkout `master` branch and merge `branchA` branch.

Follow the commands:

```
# go into repoB master branch
$ git remote add repoA <repoA-url>
$ git remote -v                     # confirm repoA is added named 'repoA'

$ git fetch repoA
$ git checkout -b branchA repoA/master
$ git mv <folder/file> repoA/<folder/file>     # repeat untill all files/folders are moved
$ git commit -am 'Moved repoA folder/file into repoA dir' 


$ git checkout master
$ git merge branchA

$ git add .
$ git commit -m 'Added repoA into repoA directory'
$ git push origin master
```

---

**Git Subtree:** You can do this using [git subtree](https://developer.atlassian.com/blog/2015/05/the-power-of-git-subtree/) also:

```
$ git subtree add --prefix=repoA/ <repoA-url> master
```

Pull `master branch of repoA` into a sub-directory named `repoA`.

Comment: I am getting fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories error after git pull repoA master

Comment: Can you attach your `commands & error details` in OP (original Post)?

Comment: BTW, Do you want to add `RepoA` into your `RepoB` as a separate repo or,  just all folders/files in the root directory?

Comment: Just as a folder in the root directory

Comment: @SasiM `--allow-unrelated-histories`.

Comment: @sajibkhan Git subtree worked. Most simple and effective solution. Thank you so much

Comment: Saved my day - thanks