# Move files to another repository with the tags

Tags: git

I would like to move a few files to another git repository, while preserving the commit history and the tags linked to those commits.

I followed this answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/11426261/245024, but the tags are not included in the patch

I'm looking for a way to reapply the tags to the new repo.

Since the relevant tags got a unique name, I can run:

```
git show-ref --tags | grep pattrn
```

to get all the tag names and commits, but since the commit in the new repo got a different hash, I can't reapply those tags

Any ideas on how to do it?

Answer (score -1):

If you use `rev-list` options `-- --all`, the `filter-branch` command will rewrite all branches and tags:

Quoting from: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch

> To rewrite the repository to look as if foodir/ had been its project
>   root, and discard all other history:
>
> ```
> git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter foodir -- --all
> ```
>
> Thus you can,
>   e.g., turn a library subdirectory into a repository of its own. Note
>   the -- that separates filter-branch options from revision options, and
>   the --all to rewrite all branches and tags.