# GIT: Is it possible to pick files or changes from a different repo with different directory structure

Tags: git

I want to pick some files and changes from a different repo which has different directory structure rather than copy things and to keep history. Is it possible in git?

Comment: Could you not simply copy/cp using the file system, then git add the new files?

Answer (score 2):

As described in "[Moving Files from one Git Repository to Another, Preserving History](http://gbayer.com/development/moving-files-from-one-git-repository-to-another-preserving-history/)", this is easier if the file(s) you want to import are in a folder: exporting/importing a folder (with its history) is easier than just a file.

> Goal: Move directory 1 from Git repository A to Git repository B.
>
> - Make a copy of repository A so you can mess with it without worrying about mistakes too much.
> - It’s also a good idea to delete the link to the original repository to avoid accidentally making any remote changes (line 3).
> - Line 4 is the critical step here.  It goes through your history and files, removing anything that is not in directory 1

That is:

```
git clone <git repository A url>
cd <git repository A directory>
git remote rm origin
git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter <directory 1> -- --all
mkdir <directory 1>
mv * <directory 1>
git add .
git commit
```

> - Make a copy of repository B if you don’t have one already.
> - On line 3, you’ll create a remote connection to repository A as a branch in repository B.
> - Then simply pull from this branch (containing only the directory you want to move) into repository B.
> - The pull copies both files and history.

Step 2:

```
git clone <git repository B url>
cd <git repository B directory>
git remote add repo-A-branch <git repository A directory>
git pull repo-A-branch master --allow-unrelated-histories
```

### git remote rm repo-A-branch

You have other options described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24693985/6309) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28031020/6309), which preserves the full path name (but forces you to specify all that you want to exclude, which is longer than specifying the one folder you want to keep).

```
# 1. clone the source
git clone ssh://<user>@<source-repo url>
cd <source-repo>
# 2. remove the stuff we want to exclude
git filter-branch --tree-filter "rm -rf <files to exclude>" --prune-empty HEAD
# 3. move to target repo and create a merge branch (for safety)
cd <path to target-repo>
git checkout -b <merge branch>
# 4. Add the source-repo as remote 
git remote add source-repo <path to source-repo>
# 5. fetch it
git pull source-repo master
```