# How to move files from a repo to another repo preserving history for moved files

Tags: git, repository

I have moved some files in a git repository to a new folder `(foo)`. When I do `git log (--follow)` on the folder, I only see one commit which is move commit.(I used `git mv` for each file)

```
test $ git log foo/
commit 97210f4e547279ab1bdb (HEAD -> develop)
Date:   Fri Aug 17 10:41:29 2018 -0400
moving files to foo folder

test $ git log --follow foo/
commit 210f4e547279ab1bdb (HEAD -> develop)
Date:   Fri Aug 17 10:41:29 2018 -0400
moving files to foo folder
```

For the files in the folder, if I try `git log --follow`, I would see all their history. 
`git log` command, however, is the same for all of them which points to commit that I moved the files.

```
test $ git log --follow foo/bar.txt
commit 97210f4e547279ab1bdb (HEAD -> develop)
Date:   Fri Aug 17 10:41:29 2018 -0400
moving files to foo folder



test $ git log --follow foo/bar.txt
commit 97210f4e547279ab1bdb (HEAD -> develop)
Date:   Fri Aug 17 10:41:29 2018 -0400
moving files to foo folder

commit 12a1dad45f70ec8d62f7
Date:   Tue Oct 24 15:12:54 2017 -0400
Canned PowerShell

commit cbe9cce205640e606e13
Date:   Thu Aug 3 20:32:00 2017 -0400
Policy for no maid
```

Now I want to move this folder and preserve the history. I tried to use this command

`git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter foo -- --all`

The result is only one commit so it doesn't preserve the history of the files before I moved them to the `foo` folder. Even `git log --follow` on the files only shows one commit. I tried googling but I couldn't find anything that preserves the history before moving the files. Any help would be appreciated.

p.s: since those files got committed to upstream and there are commits after than, I prefer not to redo the move.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GIT Split Repository directory preserving \*move / renames\* history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34568849/git-split-repository-directory-preserving-move-renames-history)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get to where you want to be, from where you are now, at least not with the current versions of Git available.

#### Why this is the case

Git does not have file history.  Git has commits; commits *are* history.  For each commit, as identified by its unique hash ID, a repository either has the commit, or lacks that commit.  Each commit preserves a snapshot of all files, gives some metadata about who made the commit (and when and why), and identifies (by hash ID) its *parent* commit, or for merges, parent commits (plural).

The `git log` command produces the history, on demand, by traversing and displaying the commits.  That is, `git log` shows one commit, then shows that commit's parent, and so on.  At merge commits, where the history forks, `git log` shows *both* commits-and-their-parents (in some order).  Using `git log --graph` forces Git to show the commits in an order that makes sense in terms of the graph that *is* the history, and at the same time, draws a crude text representation of that graph.

Given optional arguments, `git log` can traverse the history—the graph—but *omit* some of the commits, and show only commits that are particularly interesting.  This is how `git log filename` works.  Suppose you are viewing the history starting from the last commit on `master`.  If this commit's copy of file *`filename`* is *the same* as the parent commit's copy, `git log` simply *doesn't show the commit*.  It then moves back to the parent as usual.  If the *parent's parent* has a different version of file *`filename`*, `git log` shows the parent.  Then `git log` moves on to the parent's parent, and so on.

The result is that you see an *abbreviated* history, naming only those commits in which file *`filename`* has changed with respect to that particular commit's parent.  If you want to call this the file's history, that's fine: but it's not what's actually in Git, which is the *commit graph* or *commit history*, it's just *selected from* the commit history.  It *looks like* file history, until you rename a file, anyway.

Using `git log dir/` works much the same way: it walks the *commit history* as usual, but suppresses *printing* the commit unless some file within `dir/` has changed, where "changed" means *comparing parent commit to child commit shows some file(s) have changed*.

#### `git log --follow` does not work on directories

You cannot use `git log --follow` on a directory.  You can only use it on one file name.  The reason for this is that the implementation is a terrible hack.  (This might be improved someday, in the future.)  The way `--follow` works on a file is to use Git's *rename detection*.

Remember, each commit represents only a *snapshot*.  Suppose we have a parent commit with hash `G` and child with hash `H`.  The way Git decides that some file, e.g., `olddir/doc.txt`, was *renamed* between commits `G` and `H` is:

- `olddir/doc.txt` exists in `G` but not in `H`
- `newdir/doc.txt` exists in `H` but not in `G`
- the *contents* of `olddir/doc.txt` (in `G`) match those in `newdir/doc.txt` (in `H`), being either exactly bit-for-bit identical—this test is very fast—or within some similarity constraint (default 50% similar).

When `git log --follow newdir/doc.txt<` is working, it looks for a commit that touches file `olddir/doc.txt` between parent `G` and child `H`.  If it comes across a commit that apparently *renames* `olddir/doc.txt` to `newdir/doc.txt`, it prints that commit—and then *stops looking for `olddir/doc.txt` and starts looking for `newdir/doc.txt` instead*.

It does this with *exactly one full path name*.  If you have `git log` searching for directories, it never detects a rename, as it only detects renamed *files*.

(There was an attempt to fix / change this recently but it went awry.  Hopefully there will be a better version soon.)

In any case, either your repository has the commits that have the files under the old and new names, or it doesn't.  If it does not have the commits, nothing will discover them.  If it does have the commits, a future Git might be able to find whole-directory renames, but current versions of Git cannot.