# Push subfolder to GitHub, not parent directory

Tags: git, github, git-submodules, subdirectory

I have a parent directory called "Project" with two subfolders "Data" and "Writing". I have a `git` directory on "Project" and would like to `push` the "Data" folder to a private GitHub repo. I have an SSH connection to GitHub.

1. How do I `git push` just the "Data" folder on to GitHub (while keeping the "Writing" folder on my local computer)?
2. Should I create another `git` directory for the "Data" folder and `git remote` it to the GitHub repo? Or are submodules better?

I'd be grateful for the individual steps. Thank you.

Comment: Can't you use filter to keep out the 'writing' folder out of the git repo?

Comment: @Graviton Are you refering to this: https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/?

Answer (score 1):

Git does not push directories / folders; it does not even push *files*.  What Git pushes are *commits*, because this is what Git contains.  A Git *repository* is, in effect, a big database of commits.  Each commit is numbered, with a big ugly hash ID that is unique to that one particular commit,<sup>1</sup> and your repository either has some particular commit—which it finds by its number—or it does not have that commit at all.  So all Git needs to know is the number; that's how Git achieves the "distributed" part of its Distributed Version Control System existence.  You connect two Gits, and they compare their numbers (just the numbers!) to figure out who has what.

Of course, commits themselves *do* contain files.  These files have full paths—e.g., `Data/some/name.ext`, or `Writing/another/file` or whatever.  Note that the slashes are part of the file's name: there are no folders here.  Folders are an artifact of your OS, which requires that Git break these up at the slashes, and create folders.

When you *work with* files that you got *through* a Git repository, the files you work on / with are not the files that are in the commits in the repository!  (*Those* files are stored in a Git-only format, read-only, compressed, and de-duplicated across all the commits.  So the fact that *each* commit has a *complete copy* of each file doesn't matter, since two or more commits that share the same version of some file literally share a single copy.)  Git just copies the commit version of some file—well, the entire commit *snapshot* of versions of files—out into your working space, for you to work on / with.  Those *are* files, in folders, in your working tree.  But they're not *in* Git: they were *copied out of* Git, and if you make a new commit, Git will make new copies of them—or share existing copies via its de-duplication process—in a new commit.

When you use `git push`, you choose *commits* to send to some other Git.  The entire commit goes.  If you want commits that only contain files named `Data/some/name.ext`, and not any files named `Writing/another/file`, you need to make such commits.

You *can* do that in one repository, or you *can* do that by making multiple different repositories (each of which will have its own separate working tree).  It's quite tricky to do this in a single repository *if* that repository will *also* have commits that have `Writing/another/file` in them, but it can be done.

All of this is what leads to the organizations people actually use, when using Git.  In general, one repository has one working tree; that one working tree has in it the files that came out of commits in that repository.  All those files will go into future commits in that repository.<sup>2</sup>  Each commit has a full and complete snapshot of *every* file, even if the file hasn't changed.  (That's why they're de-duplicated, in the special Git-only, not-normal-files-at-all storage format inside the commits.  This is also how Git can store files that literally *can't* be extracted on your computer, if you run Windows.<sup>3</sup>)

You mention submodules.  The thing to know about submodules is: they're just another Git repository.  That is, you can have a Git repository—let's call it `outer`—that you clone:

```
git clone <url-of-outer>
cd outer                  # get into the clone we just made
```

You can now `git checkout` any commit that is in the repository you created with `git clone`, which copied all the *commits*<sup>4</sup> from some other Git that answers the phone call / text messages / whatever analogy you like, at the given URL.

Meanwhile, some or all of the commits *in* the clone you just made say, in effect: *Now, in `sub/`, get me commit `a123456` from some another Git repository.*  The *URL* for that other Git repository is in a file in each commit, named `.gitmodules`, so that your Git, on your system, can do:

```
(mkdir -p sub && cd sub && git clone <url> .)
```

or equivalent if needed, to create the `sub` clone.  Once the `sub/` directory exists and has the *other* Git repository cloned, your Git, working in `outer`, can run:

```
(cd sub && git checkout a123456)
```

to get that commit checked out.  Note that we're now up to 4 Git repositories: one at the URL you listed, yours in `outer`, one at the URL listed in `.gitmodules`, and one in `outer/sub/`.

Submodules can work pretty well, but there are several gotchas.  In short, they're more work than repositories that don't have any submodules.  They used to be so painful that people referred to them as *sob*-modules.  The situation is better now, but still not great.

The big thing here is to wrap your head around the Git model: that a *repository* holds *commits:*

- You check out a commit by its hash ID—usually, though, using a branch name to *find* the hash ID—and now you have the files from the snapshot stored in the commit.  Each commit has a full snapshot of *every* file.
- You work with *your* copies of those files in *your* working tree.
- You use `git add` to have Git update its proposed *next* commit—which started out matching the commit you got out.  The `git status` command works by comparing your proposed next commit, in Git's index aka staging-area, to what's in the current commit you checked out with `git checkout` or (in Git 2.23 or later) `git switch`.<sup>5</sup>  It also, separately, compares what's in the proposed next commit, to what's in your working tree.
- Eventually, you run `git commit` to create a *new* commit from the proposed next commit.  That commit uses the files in the index / staging-area—which is full of *every* file; `git status` only tells you about *differing* files to keep the output small—to make the new snapshot.  It also adds various bits of extra information, such as your name and email address.<sup>6</sup>
- A new commit changes which hash ID is stored in *your* branch names.  Your branch names are *yours*, not someone else's.
- Once you do have new commits, you use `git push` to send those commits to some other Git repository.  This will add your commits to *their* **branch** directly.  That is, push asks them to change their *branch* names.
- Whether or not you have new commits, you use `git fetch` to *get* new commits *from* some other Git repository—usually, the one you cloned, called `origin`.  This doesn't affect your branches!  This only updates your *remote-tracking names:* your Git's memory of their branches.
- Once you get new commits from someone else, you will probably want to incorporate them into some of *your* branches.  This requires a second command, e.g., `git merge` or `git rebase`.
- This two-comand sequence—fetch, then merge-or-rebase—is very common, so Git wraps it up into a single `git pull` command.  I recommend *avoiding* this commit if you're a beginner, because there are things that go wrong.  It's hard to know what happened when it ran *two* commands you don't really understand yet.  If you know which actual command you ran, things may still go wrong, but now you know what to *ask about*.  (But people do still like `git pull`, so if you do, just remember: it runs two commands.)

---

<sup>1</sup>This ID is unique across *all Git repositories*.  There are some unusual conditions in which one hash-ID number might be used for two different commits in two different Git repositories, but if and when that's the case, those two Git repositories can no longer talk to each other, because the commit IDs *need* to be unique.  The chance of having an ID re-used incorrectly is 1 in 2<sup>160</sup> at the current time (and eventually will be even higher), which is small enough to be ignored.

<sup>2</sup>These future commits are made from something Git calls, variously, the *index*, the *staging area*, or the *cache*, but I won't go into details here.  Just be aware of the fact that Git doesn't actually make the new commits from the working-tree files.  The index is fairly well paired-up with the working tree in some ways, but you must explicitly `git add` files to copy them back *from* the working tree, *into* the index, before committing.

If you choose to use `git commit -a`, note that this just means *run a version of `git add` before making the commit*, so you're still really using `git add`.  It's tempting to use `commit -a` to attempt to *ignore* the existence of this index / staging-area, but I find that this is unwise: Git will occasionally manage to slap you in the face with its index, and if you don't know what it is all about, you'll hate working with Git.

<sup>3</sup>For instance, Git can store a file named `aux.h`, but Windows *can't*.  If you have a commit that contains an `aux.h`, and check it out, you'll get a complaint about the file name.  Git can still work with these commits, and even make new commits containing an updated `aux.h`, though it's tricky to do that: the normal way of working, doesn't (work), because Windows can't store an `aux.h` file.  But Git can, because committed files aren't *files:* they're special Git objects, in a frozen and de-duplicated format.

<sup>4</sup>This is a bit tricky, but it's also important to realize:  When you clone a repository, you get all of their *commits*, but none of their *branches*.

More technically-correct, you get one *branch name* in your clone.  The branch name you get is up to you: you supply it, at `git clone` time, with your `-b` parameter.  For instance, `git clone -b develop <url>` has your Git create and check out a branch named `develop`.  If you *don't* give a `-b` option, your Git asks their Git which branch name *they* recommend, and uses that name.  The usual default is for your Git to use `master`, or `main` if they've switched their main branch name to `main` (e.g., newer GitHub repositories).

Meanwhile, your Git does know about *their* **branch** names.  Your Git saw them all during the `git clone` operation.  What your Git *does* with their branch names, though, is turn them into your *remote-tracking names*.  These are names like `origin/master` (or `origin/main`), `origin/develop`, and so on.  That is, we just stick the word `origin/` in front of their *branch* names, to make your *remote-tracking* names.  These names *remember* their branch names for you.

These remote-tracking names allow your Git to create your own branch names *from* their names.  But when you do that, that branch name is now *yours*.  Their Git can't mess with *your* branches because your Git keeps changing their names to your remote-tracking names.  There is a lot more to know here, but this is plenty to get started with.

<sup>5</sup>The `git checkout` command has two modes: a "safe" one that won't wreck unsaved work in your working tree, and an "unsafe" one that, if you ask Git to use it, *will*.  Unfortunately some of unsafe kinds of `git checkout` look exactly the same as the safe kinds.  This is a bad situation, and hence in Git 2.23, the Git folks split the `checkout` command into `git switch`—which is only the "safer" part—and `git restore`, which runs the "unsafe" *please wipe out my work, I've decided to throw it out* set of operations.  If you have Git 2.23 or later, it's wise to teach your fingers the new `git switch` habit.  (I'm still working on this myself.)

<sup>6</sup>This extra information is the commits *metadata*.  You don't need to learn this technical term, but you will eventually need to understand at least some of what goes in this metadata.  We'll leave that for later too though.

Answer (score 1):

> Should I create another git directory for the "Data" folder and git remote it to the GitHub repo?
> Or are submodules better?

Actually, even if you reference Data as a submodule, that still does mean Data is its own repository.

So yes:

- use [`git-filter-repo`](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/) to split `Data` (you can do so following any rename/move from the original repository: see "[Git Split Repository directory preserving *move / renames* history](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34568849/6309)")
- Then, if you want, declare the new repo as a submodule (path `/Data`) in your main repository.