# Why does git log with --follow and --reverse return only last commit?

Tags: git

I wanted to view all the commits of a file from the beginning in reverse
I ran

```
git log --reverse [file]
```

And it worked as expected.
but for a renamed file it shows only from the commit in which it was renamed so I added --follow in it.

```
git log --reverse --follow [file]
```

but it now shows only the last commit which was done for that file.

How can I combine both to get the desired result.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This seems to be [known bug](https://lore.kernel.org/git/20130524012324.295dec77@hugo.daonet.home/) in git. The only work around I can see is if you know what the file was named before, pass it along with the current file to the command, i.e.

```
 git log --reverse --follow -- oldfilename currentfilename
```

**Edit:** the following will do what you want:

```
git log --name-only --pretty="format:"  --follow <filename> | sort -u | xargs git log --reverse --
```

Comment: what if the file has been renamed more than once?

Comment: how can I use `-p` to view view changes as well?

Comment: @Shubanker, you can add whatever options you want to the end of the command, before the last `--`.

Comment: Link is down. Is this still a bug or has it been fixed since posting?