# Move file to separate repository without moving file on disk

Tags: git, repository-design

This question is related to, e.g., [How to move files from one git repo to another (not a clone), preserving history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1365541/how-to-move-files-from-one-git-repo-to-another-not-a-clone-preserving-history)
[Detach (move) subdirectory into separate Git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359424/detach-move-subdirectory-into-separate-git-repository) but the problem (or at least the solution, I think) is different. I have the following directory structure:

```
abc/
    .git/
    def/
       file1.txt
       file2.txt
    xyz/
       file3.txt
```

The directory `abc` is the root of a git repository, say `repo1`.

What I want is to put `file2.txt` in a different repository, `repo2` (local and linked to a remote). However, I do not want to move `file2.txt` out of the directory (as in the related questions). All other files and folders (`def, file1.txt, xyz/*`) have to stay in `repo1`.

When I do `git commit` or `git push`, changes to `file1.txt` should go to `repo1` and changes to `file2.txt` should go to `repo2`.

As a workaround, I could make an additional directory in `def` and move `file2.txt` there, if that makes it any easier. However, I don't want to move `file2.txt` out of the current tree.

The history of `file2.txt` does not necessarily need to be preserved in this move.

Comment: The closest thing of which I'm aware which could get close to what you want would be to use a submodule which would contain `file2.txt`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, make sure you commit or stash any change and your work tree is clean. Run `git status` to be sure.

It's possible to accomplish your goal in two easy steps.

1. Create a new empty repo in `abc/def`. Configure it to ignore everything but `file2.txt` (an any other file you want to process the same way as `file2.txt`). Add `.gitignore` and `file2.txt` to the new repo and commit:

   ```
   $ cd abc/def
   $ git init
   $ echo '*' > .gitignore
   $ echo '!/file2.txt' >> .gitignore
   $ git add .
   $ git status
   $ git commit
   ```

   Read carefully the output of `git status` and verify it added only the desired files to the repo. Commit if everything is ok or tweak `.gitignore` and the index until they reach the state you need.
2. Go to the `abc` repo, add `def/file2.txt` and `def/.gitignore` to the ignore list of this repo, remove `def/file2.txt` from the index and commit:

   ```
   $ cd ..
   $ echo '/def/file2.txt' >> .gitignore
   $ echo '/def/.gitignore' >> .gitignore
   $ git rm --cached def/file2.txt
   $ git status
   $ git commit
   ```

   Again, read the output of `git status` before committing.

#### Remarks

You can work with both repos as usual. They are independent, they are not linked in any way (apart from the fact that each repo is configured to ignore the files managed by the other one).

If you don't push the inner repo to a remote location, I recommend you to move its `.git` directory (the repository itself) somewhere outside the `abc` directory to prevent its accidental removal. The command is simple. Inside the `abc/def` directory run:

```
git init --separate-git-dir=/path-where-to-move-the-git-dir
```

You can run this command line when you create the `abc/def` repo or you can run it after that. The data contained in the repo is safe. It only moves the repo to the indicated location.

Comment: Nice, I didn't know the option to create a repository in a separate directory. I notice it's creating a file `.git` which contains the path to the actual git directory. Would this file also needed to be ignored by the "host" repository, like `.gitignore` and `file2.txt`, or is it handled specially?

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks! I guess I have to manually change both `.gitignore`s when I rename a file?

Comment: *" I notice it's creating a file .git which contains the path to the actual git directory."* -- that's what the [documentation of `git init`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-init#git-init---separate-git-dirltgitdirgt) says too. I didn't find an official reference yet but it seems Git knows that a file or a folder named `.git` in the working tree makes its parent directory a Git repo and it ignores the `.git` file or directory without being told so. The Git handling of [submodules](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule) also use this technique.

Comment: Indeed, you have to change both `.gitignore` files if you want to rename the file. Remember that the file `abc/.gitignore` tells the outer repo what files to ignore and the file `abc/def/.gitignore` tells the inner repo what files to **not** ignore.

Comment: Alternatively, you can put the name of `file2.txt` in [`.git/info/exclude`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) (instead of `.gitignore`) in one or both repos. The advantage is that you don't need to change and commit `.gitignore` anymore if you add/remove/rename files in the inner repo. The disadvantage is that `.git/info/exclude` is local to the repo. It cannot be pushed to a remote repository.