# Moving repo folders to hard drive and saving git history from .git file

Tags: git, github

I am backing up my hard drive of my project repos. I have a lot of work so I wanted to back them up on a SSD. When I just copied them, in the console, it showed a completely clean history. I wanted to essentially clone the repo but also keep my git history so it is an replica of what I have on my machine, with all of my commits in tact.

I looked into this solution here: [How to move files from one git repo to another (not a clone), preserving history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1365541/how-to-move-files-from-one-git-repo-to-another-not-a-clone-preserving-history)

I wanted to try taking out the commits as a patch. Of the best and simplest solutions was

`cd repository
git log --pretty=email --patch-with-stat --reverse --full-index --committer-date-is-author-date --binary -- path/to/file_or_folder > patch
cd ../another_repository
git am < ../repository/patch`

Am I going about this the right way? or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried just cloning the repo onto the SSD?

Comment: @Steve No I have not cloned from the repo. If I did, I would have to do it for each one I have on my drive.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to backup, good solutions are:

- use `git clone --mirror`
- use `git bundle` feature (made for backup ;-))