# How to create new repository from selected files?

Tags: git

Let say I have code for application and two libraries in my repository.

```
$ tree -d .    
.
├── app
├── libA
└── libB
```

At some point the `libA` is growing complex. I would like to make it a new separated repository for easy management. And to be able to use with another application.

Is there any way to extracted **only** files in `libA` along with its history to created new repository without any history of other files outside?

Comment: Normally library files are not versioned/stored in Git, because Git doesn't handle binary files well.  Can you tell us more about what is inside these lib folders?

Comment: Sorry for confusion, all files are just plain source codes.

Comment: You could look into using submodules, but how big is your repo?

Comment: Actually the size is not main problem, I also want to use `libA` in another app. (question edited)

Comment: I think submodules might work in your case then.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `--subdirectory-filter`

How ever Looks like a duplicate of [How to move files from one git repo to another (not a clone), preserving history](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1365541/3444930).