# Copying the commit history from one repo to another

Tags: git

I'm trying to copy the commit history (`git log`) from one repo to another. I have found another [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1365541/how-to-move-files-from-one-git-repo-to-another-not-a-clone-preserving-history) that asked a similar question. The solution was to run:

```
git log --pretty=email --patch-with-stat --reverse -- path/to/file_or_folder | (cd /path/to/new_repository && git am)
```

I have run it, and it looks like it works (the log history the same). But this change is only local. How can I do it to remote also?
I can't use `git add` and then `git commit` because I don't have anything to commit.
How can I change the history of the new repo to be the same as the old repo (they both contain the same files without changes).

Comment: You might be interested in the Git book on [working with remotes](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes) since this can be done entirely by connecting the two repositories and fetching and merging them.

Comment: I'm familiar with the book and the commands. I'm just afraid to make some stupid mistake that I can't revert.  I have the two repos locally. How can I merge them so the first one will stay as it and the second one will have all the log history?

Comment: If you want the other to be the same as the former, then you could just throw away the second and make a fresh clone.

Comment: Commit history *is* commits. Just fetch the commits. In the target repository, you will need some sort of name—a branch name, or a tag name, or something like that—to remember the *last* commit, from which you can find all of the earlier commits. The `git fetch` command sets such a name for you, called a *remote-tracking* name.

Comment: If you intend to send the commits in the other direction—from your Git to theirs—you have two choices: have them `git fetch` from you, or use `git push`, which is as close as there is to the opposite of `git fetch`. The advantage and drawback of `git push` is that `git push` needs to set one of *their* names in *their* repository: as the one doing the `git push`, you select which name you'll ask them to set. There is no such thing as a remote-tracking name in this case.