# How to filter-branch keeping history of a folder beyond renames?

Tags: git

The problem I have is I need to move folder `A` from `repo A` into `repo B`. Folder `A` has files that were recently moved from another folder `B` in the same repo. Viewing commit log for a single file shows just couple commits unless `--follow` flag is specified. When I am using `filter-branch` for using subdirectory filter (following command), I am loosing history that is accessible with `--follow`.

```
git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter <directory> -- --all
```

I've found many similar answers to this problem, for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1365541/how-to-move-files-from-one-git-repo-to-another-not-a-clone-preserving-history), but seems like it doesn't help.

Comment: Git has neither file nor folder history. The only history in a Git repository is the collection of commits in the repository. The commits *are* the history. `filter-branch` allows you to copy commits; the new commits are new history and the original commits are the original history. If you stop using the original commits, the new history is what you have.

Comment: When you use `git log --follow`, that doesn't actually do anything special. Instead, what it does is look at the most recent commit(s) and see if those commits *changed* the (one, single) named file. If so, it *shows* those commits. Then, in any case, it moves back to their parent(s). If those didn't change the one file, it doesn't show them. As it goes, it shows only the selected commits ... *but*, if the selected commit changes the file by *renaming* it (this detection depends on the parent and child commits), it starts looking for the *old name*.

Comment: If you use filter-branch with `--subdirectory-filter`, you're building new commits that only keep the files you've named. This doesn't start looking for the *old* name, in some other location. The new commits you build with filter-branch only *have* the new name. There's no rename to follow, in the new history.

Comment: Thanks @torek, this is perfectly explains the result I see (loosing commits with old name). I am thinking that if I will remove everything else from the repo using `--tree-filter` excerpt folder `A` that I want to keep, this might help since `old-name` is not in the path that I am deleting.