# git extract directory from repository - commit history prior to renaming is missing

Tags: git

I want to extract a directory from a repository, including all its commit history. The problem I'm having is that the end result, does not contain commit history prior to moving/renaming the files (which was done at some point).

Example:

- I want to extract src/lib/features/TheLib from a project repository.
- This directory 'theLib' used to be in a different location at some point, e.g. 'src/util/lib/TheLib'.
- The main repository contains full history of changes made to the files, including changes before the lib was moved to a new location within the repo.
- If I try to extract the directory into a new repository, I only have the commit history from the point after the files were moved/renamed.

I have tried this [0]:

```
$ git filter-branch --prune-empty --subdirectory-filter src/lib/features/TheLib master
```

and this [1]:

```
$ ./git-filter-repo --subdirectory-filter src/lib/features/TheLib
```

Both tools give me the same results. It almost works fine, except no commit history prior to renaming.

[0] https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/using-git/splitting-a-subfolder-out-into-a-new-repository

[1] https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/main/Documentation/converting-from-filter-branch.md#cheat-sheet-conversion-of-examples-from-the-filter-branch-manpage

Comment: I'm thinking that this could be done with a bash script that would retrieve all commits related to the files in the directory and re-apply them one by one in a new repository. However, I don't want to re-invent the wheel if something like this already exists.

Comment: On the site https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch is a warning and it's recommended to use https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/ instead. I used it once and it worked well.