# How do I move my git project to a subdirectory for all commits, except one file?

Tags: git, git-filter-repo

I'm trying to move my entire repo root into a sub-directory, for everything except one file.

For example, I have something like:

```
root
-Folder1
-Folder2
-.gitattributes
```

And for all commits and history, I want

```
root
-ProjectA
--Folder1
--Folder2
-.gitattributes
```

i.e., I want to move everything *except* .gitattributes to a subdirectory. If I use

```
 git filter-repo --to-subdirectory-filter ProjectA/
```

everything gets moved. I can't find the strategy for moving everything except a single file.

How do I keep the file where it is? Or how do I move just that file back up to the root with another command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can, you would list all elements except `.gitattributes`, and rename them in one command, using [path renaming](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/docs/html/git-filter-repo.html#_renaming_based_on_paths_see_also_filename_callback):

```
git filter-repo --path-rename Folder1:ProjectA/Folder1 \
                --path-rename Folder2:ProjectA/Folder2 \
                ...
```

The [OP House](https://stackoverflow.com/users/737147/house) suggests in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70585184/how-do-i-move-my-git-project-to-a-subdirectory-for-all-commits-except-one-file/70586855?noredirect=1#comment124795507_70586855) the more sensible approach:

- moving everything to a subdir,
- then moving the `.gitattributes` back with `--path-rename 'ProjectA/.gitattributes:.gitattributes'`

*[Note the single quotes around the parameter value - this avoids the bug/issue with filenames starting with '.']*

I would do each step in a separately cloned repository, to make sure I can go back to the original one if it fails.
The second step would be done in a clone of the repository from the first step.

Comment: WHOA. VonC. Man!

Comment: I did actually try this route, and ended up with a completely empty repo. The issue I see with this approach is, if somewhere in the history there was another file/folder in the root, it wouldn't be properly moved by moving all the files/folders that are currently in the root.
git-filter-repo seems to have a bug related to moving files starting with a `.`, because I also tried moving everything to a subdir, then moving the `.gitattributes` back with `--path-rename ProjectA/.gitattributes:.gitattributes`, but it didn't believe there was a colon in the argument and failed to process.

Comment: @House I like your second approach. It should have worked.

Comment: It should, yes, but the bug prevents it (where it says the argument is invalid). I even tried using the file approach, creating a file with `ProjectA/.gitattributes=>.gitattributes`. Unfortunately, this just freezes when rewriting commits.

Comment: @House Can you try the second step (`--path-rename ProjectA/.gitattributes:.gitattributes`) in a clone of the repository from the first step?

Comment: The command doesn't even execute, I get `--path-rename expects one colon in its argument` when trying to run that command. filter-repo appears to have a bug that prevents it from parsing the ":." part.

Comment: @House And what about escaping the dot? `:\.gitignore`

Comment: This does allow the command to run, but breaks the repo by introducing a file with a bad path: `error: invalid path '\.gitattributes' 
fatal: Could not reset index file to revision 'HEAD'`

Comment: I think the move everything, then move one thing back is the right approach, but the behavior from filter-repo is unexpected. So, I'll select this as the correct answer, even though a bug prevents it from being accomplished.

Comment: Found a workaround for the "expected one colon in its argument" bug - wrap parameter value in single quotes. Edited answer.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is late but there is another option which achieves the same goal and feels a little better IMO. I used this for migrating a dozen+ repos into a single monorepo:

```bash
# On the old project, create a "migrate" branch
git checkout -b migrate

# Move the files/folders to a new location. 
# NOTE: This rewrites the git history to make it appear the files were there the whole time!
git filter-repo --path Folder1 --path Folder2 --to-subdirectory-filter packages/project-a
```

You can specify many paths which you want to be moved into the subdirectory in a single move. If you are migrating to a monorepo, the `--to-subdirectory-filter` should match the final destination you want in your monorepo (ex. `packages/project-a`). Then, in your monorepo, you would do the following:

```
git remote add old-project <PATH/TO/OLD/PROJECT>
git fetch old-project migrate
git merge remotes/old-project/migrate --allow-unrelated-histories
git remote remove old-project
```

You should now see all of your files located at `packages/project-a` inside the monorepo, with git history preserved. SEE: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61917589/264794

Comment: Interesting alternative. Upvoted.