Moving folders into newly created folder while preserving history
I have a bitbucket git repository which has two big folders (Folder1 and Folder2) with huge and important commit history inside. I want to create two new folders (NewParentFolder1 and NewParentFolder2) and move these two folders into their new respective parents.
Most Importantly:  Not losing both folders original commit history
Current directory structure:
Project1->
 - Folder1 
 - Folder2
 - otherFolders 
 - otherFiles 
 - .gitignore

Desired directory structure:
Project1->
 - NewParentFolder1 
      - Folder1 
 - NewParentFolder2 
      - Folder2 
 - otherFolders 
 - otherFiles
 - .gitignore

Thanks, in advance.

Git does not concern itself with renamed files. Moving a file will not cause you to lose history unless you perform other edits in the same commit.

@Dai: that may be true for files, however, git log NewParentFolder1/Folder1 will not show all commits, even with --follow.

@ArkadiuszDrabczyk that's because git doesn't track directories at all.

@Dai: so OP cannot achieve their goal if I understood the question correctly.

@ArkadiuszDrabczyk No, I'm saying the OP's question is predicated on a misunderstanding of how git works. i.e. their question is invalid - i.e. moot.

@Dai: No - so can OP achieve what they want?

@ArkadiuszDrabczyk The OP wants to ensure their git history is preserved, i.e. they want assurances that their IDE's git-based "File history" feature will continue to show the same history as-now after doing this re-org, and my answer is "yes, it will continue to work, provided they only rename/move files and not make any other edits in the same commit" - that will ensure the files retain identical content-hashes and so will be fully trackable through renames.

@Dai: The OP wants to ensure their git history is preserved, i.e. they want assurances that their IDE's git-based "File history" feature will continue to show the same history this is not how I read the question, they want git log NewParentFolder1/Folder1 to show all commits done in Folder1 before it was moved.

@ArkadiuszDrabczyk They never said they were using git's CLI. I'm assuming they don't use git's CLI because if they were a CLI user then I'd expect them to know about how git tracks files.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/70586855/7976758 git filter-repo --path-rename Folder1:NewParentFolder1/Folder1 --path-rename Folder2:NewParentFolder2/Folder2 Must be done in a clean clone; or create a backup and use --force. Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-filter-repo%5D+move+directory

Thanks, This is what i was looking for.
After doing forced path-rename, there is nothing to commit.
So i wonder how i can push this renamed information to bitbucket?

git push --all --force because you rewrote the entire history.
